# How to properly instantiate a MultiSet (created on my own) using Python

Tags: python, data-structures, multiset

I wanted to learn about Data Structures so I decided to create them using Python. I first created a Singly Linked List (which consists of two classes: the actual List and the Node). A List consists of Nodes (or can be empty). Each node had a "next" value. When I instantiated a list, it would look like this:

```
l = LinkedList([1,2])
```

and this was the sudocode for the **init**:

```
def __init__(self, item=None):
    head = None

    if a single item was given
        head = Node(item)
        head.next = None
    else if multiple items were given
        for i in item
            if head: # i is not the first item in the list
                new_head = Node(i)
                new_head.next = head
                head = new_head
            else: # i is the first item in the list
                head = Node(i)
                head.next = None
```

Maybe there is a flaw in the logic above, but hopefully you get how it works more or less. The key thing I noted here was that I did not use any list ([]) or array ({}) because I didn't need to.

Now, I am trying to create a MultiSet but I am stuck in the **init** part.
It was simple for a Linked Lists because when I read articles on Linked Lists, all of the articles immediately mentioned a List class and a Node class (a List consists of a Node. a List has a head and a tail. a Node has a 'next' value). But when I read articles on MultiSets, they just mention that multisets are sets (or bags) of data where multiple instances of the same data are allowed.

This is my **init** for my multiset so far:

```
def __init__(self, items=None):
    self.multiset = []
    if items: # if items is not None
        try:
            for i in items: # iterate through multiple items (assuming items is a list of items)
                self.multiset.append(i)
        except: # items is only one item
            self.multiset.append(items)
```

I don't think I am on the right track though because I'm using a Python list ([]) rather than implementing my own (like how I did with a Linked List using Nodes, list.head, list.tail and node.next).

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I would create and instantiate my own MultiSet using Python (without using existing Python lists / arrays)? Or am I already on the right track and am I supposed to be using Python lists / arrays when I am creating my own MultiSet data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're conflating two things:

- data structures - using Python (or any other language, basically), you can implement linked lists, balanced trees, hash tables, etc.
- mapping semantics - any container, but an associative container in particular, has a protocol: what does it do when you insert a key that's already in it? does it have an operation to access all items with a given key? etc.

So, given your linked list, you can certainly implement a multiset (albeit with not that great performance), because it's mainly a question of your decision. One possible way would be:

- Upon an insert, append a new node with the key
- For a find, iterate through the nodes; return the first key you find, or `None` if there aren't any
- For a find_all, iterate through the nodes, and return a list (or your own linked-list, for that matter), of all the keys matching it.

---

Similarly, a linked-list, by itself, doesn't dictate if you have to use it as a set or a dictionary (or anything else). These are orthogonal decisions.

Comment: hm, interesting. Okay, so does that mean it is okay for me to use Python's built in list ([]) to instantiate my MultiSet (like how I did in my code above) just as it is okay for me to use my own Linked List?

Comment: @user2719875 yes, it's just a matter of your decision.